# How do I install PyProj module for Python 2.7 on Windows 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, josm

I am having trouble installing the pyproj module for Python 2.7 on Windows 7.  I have tried both the 32 and 64 bit installers from [this list](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/downloads/list) but the install crashes each time I run it.  I have the Python 2.7 version that installs with ArcMap 10.2.2 loaded on my machine.  I need pyproj to run the [Scanaerial](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/Scanaerial) plugin in JOSM to locate water sources in my county.  Any ideas on what could be causing the crash, or how to install pyproj properly?

Comment: did you right click 'run as administrator' on installers win7 upwards.

Comment: That solved part of it, I also had to install a second instance of Python because the modules weren't recognizing the existing Python27 directory.  Thanks!

Comment: then set your var paths http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/setting-up-windows-python-path-system-variable.php

Comment: I followed the guide but when I try to install the prproj or PIL modules they cannot find the Python 2.7 directory still.  Not sure what I am missing.